# R: Replicating a loop or function multiple times and adding results to data frame for each time

Tags: r, for-loop, user-defined-functions, random, replicate

I've written an R loop and turned it into a function that takes in a dataframe, The original code and data frame are below. The goal is to repeat out this function or loop 1000 times and end up with a data frame that has 1000 columns representing the rowsums for each row.name.

MY GOAL, is data frame that looks like this

```
row.names   rsum_s1  rsum_s2  rsum_s3  rsum_s4.....rsum_s1000 
kc231       40       57       15       34
kc25498     34       39       567      23
kc087398    28       3747     25       1938
```

x is the original data frame and it  looks like this:

```
row.names   val2        val4        val3        val4
kc231       1.62E-08    3.29E-37    1.36E-14    0.29692426
kc25498     4.93E-01    4.93E-01    4.93E-01    0.49330053
kc087398    3.50E-01    1.18E-22    1.71E-08    0.35011743
```

LOOP I first wrote works to give me  rsum_s as a list.

```
  for(k in 1:length(colnames(x))) {  
        as.numeric(x[,k])
        sample(x[,k])
        x[,k]<-rank(x[,k],ties.method="min")
        rsum_s<-rowSums(x)
```

Output of LOOP the rank sums for each row.name id in each row: rsum_s

```
structure(c(47, 142, 82), .Names = c("kc231", "kc25498", "kc087398"))
```

LOOP converted into FUNCTION

```
sim<-function(x) { #takes a data.frame
  for(k in 1:length(colnames(x))) {  #each column set as numeric
    as.numeric(x[,k])
    sample(x[,k])  #randomly shuffle values in each column
    x[,k]<-rank(x[,k],ties.method="min") #rank each randomly shuffled columns
    rsum_s<-rowSums(x) #take the sum of the rows
    return(rsum_s)
    }
}
```

Result of function is in integers instead of whole numbers.

```
sim(dataframe1)
kc231   kc25498 kc087398
18.24   37.47   32.350117
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I need to do the loop 1000 times and append the column of rank sums for each time the loop is run to a data frame or replicate function sim 1000 times and convert all the results to a data frame that would work. So if anyone can help me in completing this task it would be great

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you meant to write:

```
sim <- function(x) { #takes a data.frame
  for(k in 1:ncol(x)) {  #each column set as numeric
    x[,k] <- as.numeric(x[, k])
    x[,k] <- sample(x[, k])  #randomly shuffle values in each column
    x[,k] <- rank(x[, k], ties.method = "min") #rank each randomly shuffled columns
  }
  rsum_s <- rowSums(x) #take the sum of the rows
  return(rsum_s)  
}
```

Some of the things you did wrong:

1. `as.numeric` and `sample` had no effect unless you assign the result, but most importantly
2. the `rowSums` and `return` had to be moved to the end, outside the `for` loop, otherwise the function would exit after processing the first column.

The code above is still not very efficient because at each iteration you are replacing the whole `x` multiple times. I would recommend you look at the `apply` family of functions, do something like:

```
sim <- function(x) {
    fun <- function(z) rank(sample(as.numeric(z)), ties.method = "min")
    y   <- as.data.frame(lapply(x, process.one.col))
    rownames(y) <- rownames(x)
    rowSums(y)
}
```

Comment: thank you. didn't end up using that code exactly but it did work for me!